# How to visualize large amount of particles?

Tags: interactive-visualization, data-visualization

Often as a result of several simulations which are themselves intensive a huge amount of information i.e., points/line/plane depending to the subject of investigation are available. Although there are extensive list of multivariate analysis and data-mining techniques to summarize the results however I am often amazed by a simple visualization giving the most of the information in one shot.
Being familiar with some techniques in visualization e.g., application of OpenGL etc I would like to ask:  1- Is there any **software/technique/framework**/etc providing ability to visualize several million particles (points/lines/...)?
2- What is the most favorite application in the community of statistics? I'm not fan of **R**! What else?

**Note:**
Let consider 3D data to be visualized **interactively**, so rotation and selection (slicing) being available **realtime**.

Comment: (1) What *are* you a fan of?  (2) How many dimensions do your "points/lines/..." have?

Comment: Python is my favorite programming language even having less comprehensive statistical packages compared to R. The question was updated with dimension info.

Answer (score 3):

[ParaView](http://www.paraview.org/) and [VisIt](https://wci.llnl.gov/codes/visit/) are two tools designed for such uses, visualizing large and high dimensional scientific data sets with interactive slicing and manipulation.